# rubyonrails js.erb not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a very basic Ajax request in Ruby on Rails and I need to do it without user intervention, so inside of script tags on my main form I have:

```
<script>
    var xhhtp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("POST","setday:day=4");
    xhttp.send();
</script>
```

In my rails controller, which does properly receive this request I have the following:

```
def setday
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :layout => false }  // I have tried it without the render
    end
end
```

And in my `setday.js.erb` file I have:

```
alert ("page was loaded");
```

The alert is not being executed, this bare bones case proved to me that setday.js.erb is not rendering...  any ideas ??

Comment: Check the network tab within Chrome. Are you seeing the XHR request go out? If so, what's the response code/body?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
xhttp.open("POST","setday:day=4.js");
```

to force js format.
You can leave

```
format.js { }
```